# How to hide SSH key to the Docker image without leaving the trace?

Tags: security, docker, containers, ssh-keys

If I add my private SSH key to my Docker image, how can I hide it without leaving the trace, so no one (except me) can access it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. IMHO. As long as your target audience is capable of doing `docker diff` and `docker run --entry-point`.

Answer (score 0):

Work-around:

Generate (or store) the key locally on the host machine

```
ssh-keygen -f mydockerkey -N ''
```

Then use a volume mapping to insert this file dynamically into the container at runtime:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/mydockerkey:/root/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu find /root/.ssh -type f
/root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Thank you - I will have a go.